# Javascript anonymous function remapped on same array twice do both mappings work or old one is replaced?

Tags: javascript, arrays, anonymous-function, remap

I converted this JavaScript to Java and it seems to work great, but some glitches still remain  I'm trying to fix them and so far this is one of the problems I think exist.

JavaScript anonymous function remapped on same array twice do both mappings work or old one is replaced? if it's replaced why does this exist here? I'm 99% certain it gets replaced with the next functions, since it could be either `cGBC` or not `cGBC` there should be no reason this line `this.memoryHighWriter[0x2] = this.memoryHighWriteNormal;` should be in any effect, but I'm not sure.

As far as I understand that `memoryWriteJumpCompile` function also initializes all addresses from `0` to `0xFFFF` with whatever each address does if it has no use later in the future it still gets a default operation..

But why even give a default operation for `this.memoryHighWriter[0x2] = this.memoryHighWriteNormal;` if it still gets replaced either way in the next function.

The full source code is at : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grantgalitz/GameBoy-Online/master/js/GameBoyCore.js

This below call is called in `memoryWriteJumpCompile` function.

```
this.registerWriteJumpCompile();                //Compile the I/O write functions separately...
```

```
GameBoyCore.prototype.registerWriteJumpCompile = function () {
    //I/O Registers (GB + GBC):
    ...
    //SC (Serial Transfer Control):
    this.memoryHighWriter[0x2] = this.memoryHighWriteNormal;
    this.memoryWriter[0xFF02] = this.memoryWriteNormal;
    ...
    this.recompileModelSpecificIOWriteHandling();
    this.recompileBootIOWriteHandling();
};
```

The `recompileModelSpecificIOWriteHandling();` is called right after the  `registerWriteJumpCompile` is finished.

```
GameBoyCore.prototype.recompileModelSpecificIOWriteHandling = function () {
    if (this.cGBC) {
        //GameBoy Color Specific I/O:
        //SC (Serial Transfer Control Register)
        this.memoryHighWriter[0x2] = this.memoryWriter[0xFF02] = function (parentObj, address, data) {
            if (((data & 0x1) == 0x1)) {
                //Internal clock:
                parentObj.memory[0xFF02] = (data & 0x7F);
                parentObj.serialTimer = ((data & 0x2) == 0) ? 4096 : 128; //Set the Serial IRQ counter.
                parentObj.serialShiftTimer = parentObj.serialShiftTimerAllocated = ((data & 0x2) == 0) ? 512 : 16; //Set the transfer data shift counter.
            } else {
                //External clock:
                parentObj.memory[0xFF02] = data;
                parentObj.serialShiftTimer = parentObj.serialShiftTimerAllocated = parentObj.serialTimer = 0; //Zero the timers, since we're emulating as if nothing is connected.
            }
        }
            ...
    } else {
            ...
        //Fill in the GameBoy Color I/O registers as normal RAM for GameBoy compatibility:
        //SC (Serial Transfer Control Register)
        this.memoryHighWriter[0x2] = this.memoryWriter[0xFF02] = function (parentObj, address, data) {
            if (((data & 0x1) == 0x1)) {
                //Internal clock:
                parentObj.memory[0xFF02] = (data & 0x7F);
                parentObj.serialTimer = 4096; //Set the Serial IRQ counter.
                parentObj.serialShiftTimer = parentObj.serialShiftTimerAllocated = 512; //Set the transfer data shift counter.
            } else {
                //External clock:
                parentObj.memory[0xFF02] = data;
                parentObj.serialShiftTimer = parentObj.serialShiftTimerAllocated = parentObj.serialTimer = 0; //Zero the timers, since we're emulating as if nothing is connected.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's just an ordinary array element. When you reassign it, it replaces the old value. There's nothing special about it just because you put functions in it.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but then I started wondering maybe it creates 2 arrays elements on the same index which both get executed at the same time javascript is unpredictable like that at times. I guess it's just old code the author forgot to remove.

Comment: Javascript is not unpredictable like that. Its arrays are pretty much the same as in most languages.